# Maximum width of text in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

I need to check the width of text that a user enters and not allow any further entry if it exceeds a maximum value. I know how to measure the width of the text in a div, using the current font and font size. I test the width of the text with the following function:

```
editor.on("change", function (ev) {
          var imprintText = editor.getData();
          var textWidth = measureText(imprintText);

          var hfMaxImprintWidth = document.getElementById("<%=hfMaxImprintWidth.ClientID%>");
          var maxWidth = hfMaxImprintWidth.value;

          if (textWidth >= maxWidth) {
          };
        });
```

But I don't know how to keep additional characters from being added to the textarea. I'd also like to limit the text to one line (no line breaks or new paragraphs). Can someone please help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean rendered width or amount of characters? Meaning, what does `measureText()` do? Should it return something like '300px' or '54'? How do you measure it inside a div? If that works, why not insert `imprintText` into a temp div, measure that and then use that calculation?

Comment: That's just what `measureText` does: It puts the text in a temp div and returns its width in pixels. I want to know how to intercept CKEditor adding the next character to the textbox if this maximum width has been reached or exceeded. I want to stop allowing more input in the editor window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too long to be a comment - how appropriate.

Sounds like something that I would solve by using a workaround. For example, if the text is too long, set CKEditor background color to red and prevent saving. Like some websites do for comments - for example stackoverflow shows "too long by 27 characters". Do a similar message on save: display an alert that whines to the user that they have too much content but just leave the character count out.

As for "no line breaks or new paragraphs" - this could be a little more complex. Advanced Content Filter can easily deal with the line breaks, but for the one paragraph only limit I think what you could do is again always check during save and alert the user.

As for automated trickery, how about something like capturing the `key` event and checking `if (evt.data.keyCode === 13) {}` and deleting the new element from the editable.

Better still, if the enter key event is cancelable, you could try `evt.cancel()` as well to ignore it completely. Sorry no example code.

Comment: Thanks! That's helpful.